# Return results if at least one node (related but possibly not a result) has a certain property, in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that consists of a set of disjoint family trees.

I have a working query that has a few `OPTIONAL MATCH` statements, which allow me to get only the immediate parents and siblings of someone in the `main_person`'s family tree, assuming that those relatives are of interest to us:

```
MATCH (p:Person {main_person: 'y'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[]-(parent:Person)
  WHERE parent.`person_of_interest` = 'y'
OPTIONAL MATCH (parent:Person)-[]->(sib:Person)
  WHERE sib <> p
  AND sib.`person_of_interest` = 'y'
RETURN
  p, parent, sib;
```

But say I want to qualify this by making sure:

- at least one member of a family has a `test_me = 'y'` property. This can be a far, distant member of the family. It definitely doesn't have to be family member that is a `person_of_interest`, or is a close family member.

If at least one of them has this property, then we can return the family members we are looking for. But if nobody has the property, then we don't want any results for that family.

I'm not sure how to construct this. I keep trying to start with the `test_me = 'y'` part, and carry it with a `WITH`:

```
 MATCH (p:Person)-[]-(m)
 WHERE ANY m.test_me = 'y'
 WITH p, m 
 . . .
```

Maybe it should be more like:

```
MATCH (p:Person {main_person: 'y'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[]-(parent:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (parent:Person)-[]->(sib:Person)
WHERE sib <> p
HAVING <condition here>
RETURN
p, parent, sib;
```

If this were SQL, I'd try to use a temp table to pipe things along.

None of it is really working.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED to answer updated question]

This query *may* work for you (or it may run out of memory or appear to run forever):

```
MATCH (p:Person {main_person: 'y'})
  WHERE EXISTS((p)-[*0..]-({test_me: 'y'}))
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<--(parent:Person)
  WHERE parent.person_of_interest = 'y'
OPTIONAL MATCH (parent:Person)-->(sib:Person)
  WHERE sib <> p AND sib.person_of_interest = 'y'
RETURN p, COLLECT(parent) AS parents, COLLECT(sib) AS sibs;
```

The `[*0..]` syntax denotes a variable length relationship search where the matching paths can have 0 or more relationships. The reason the query uses a lower bound of `0` instead of `1` (which is the default) is this: we also want to also test whether `p` itself has the desired `test_me` property value.

However, variable length relationship searches are notorious for using a lot of memory or taking a long time to finish when no upper bound is specified, so normally a query would specify a *reasonable* upper bound (e.g., `[*0..5]`).

By the way, you should probably pass values such as 'y' as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypher-parameters) instead of hard-coding them.

Comment: cybersam, I owe you an apology. I am really thankful you answered this question, but I had to go back and make an edit to the question. I regret this!!!

Comment: This is really interesting. I noticed that the order of the `OPTIONAL MATCH` statements makes a big difference. In my 'real life' problem, the order was reversed, and I got no results. I eventually changed the order, and it worked as expected. Anyway, thanks again for all your patience and help.

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely on the right track, I think you already have your answer even if you don't realize it.

What you have in your description works as the start of your query, with just a few modifications:

```
MATCH pattern=(p:Person{main_person: 'y'})-[*]-()
WHERE ANY (person IN nodes(pattern) WHERE person.test_me = 'y')
WITH p
...
```

The variable relationship lets you consider every person in the tree (if there are non-family relationships in your graph, you'll want to use types on your relationship to ensure you're only considering a single family's tree), as well as the main_person. If nobody in p's family tree has your desired property, p will be null, and any subsequent matchings using p will yield no results. This should let you specify the rest of the query freely, and as long as all matches include p, you shouldn't get any results at the end for families without the desired property value.

EDIT fixed my query a bit, the ANY() clause wasn't written correctly.

Comment: looks like something in the `nodes(pattern)` is slowing things down

Comment: You can cancel and run an EXPLAIN on the query to see where things aren't working. Some other things to check...whatever property you're using to match on a specific person (your main_person) should be uniquely constrained. You may also want to check the size of the tree you're matching on from the main_person, since variable relationships will span the entire connected subgraph. Is each family tree a complete subgraph, or are there relationships that escape the family tree and possibly link more nodes in your graph than those you want to search?